# Using one view in the other views of backbone.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I try to use a typo to make my code into an easy piece of cake.

Example I have a `sign in form` in my html file (I'm using `text.js` to seperate forms into different html file).

Then I have more than two views have to include `sign in form` in it :

```
define(["jquery" ,
    "underscore" ,
    "backbone" ,
    "text!templates/Layout/signIn.html"
    //the others file
    ],function($ , _ , Backbone, SignIn){

    var viewA = Backbone.View.extend({
      initialize: function() {

       },
       events : {
        'click #signInBtn' : 'signIn'
       },
       signIn : function(){
        //do sign in action ....
        console.log("View A");
       }
     });
     return viewA;
});


define(["jquery" ,
    "underscore" ,
    "backbone" ,
    "text!templates/Layout/signIn.html"
    //the others file
    ],function($ , _ , Backbone, SignIn){

    var viewB = Backbone.View.extend({
      initialize: function() {

       },
       events : {
        'click #signInBtn' : 'signIn'
       },
       signIn : function(){
        //do sign in action ....
        console.log("View A");
       }
     });
     return viewB;
});
```

As in these two views, `signIn` function is written two times. So I want to create a `SignInView` to handle the `singInBtn` event.

Is it a good idea to do that? If so, how?

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Why would you have two identical views with the same events and handlers? If this is necessary at all just use either of the two as "SignInView", since they are exactly the same.

Comment: @aurbano, Ah no, actually the two views are used in different things. Just typo in here dear.

Comment: I'm not really understanding your question, but you can certainly create a *base signinview* and then have our two views extend that view.